# Sending / Receiving links issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have developped a chat application on my phone. I noticed that when my messages  are links, they are not recognized.

So I used regex to solve the issue and met an other problem.

Here is the string I'm sending :

```
var input = document.getElementById("myMessage").value;
var mm = input.replace(/((?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\s]+)/g,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

The received string is like this :

```
receivedMessage.replace(/((?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\s]+)/g,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

For instance, if I send : www.google.com, the guy at the other side of the chat receives :

```
www.google.com'>www.google.com'>www.google.com
```

while I'm expecting

```
www.google.com
```

I don't understand why am I getting this. Should the reveiving string be formatted like the opposite of the sending string ? meaning

```
receivedMessage.replace("<a href='$1'>$1</a>",/((?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\s]+)/g);
```

I don't know regex at all so I may tell crap.

Comment: And what if the input is `"google.com"` or maybe `"http://www"`. Than your regex will fail.

Comment: http links work fine and for an other reason the links are all in http://

Comment: Your regex should work for the mentioned case (`"www.google.com"`). I ran it and it seems to work. The problem maybe lays somewhere else. Where does `receivedMessage` comes from? What do you do with `mm`?

Comment: They are both attached as the innerHTML of a <p> HTML tag

Comment: If all links start with `http://` or `https://` than it is ok for the first remark. But if you have links like `http://www` or `http://whatever`, they will be proceeded, although they are not valid links. That was my objection.

Comment: You say if it starts with http:// is ok then you say http:// www isn't ok. Isn't this last one starts with http:// ?

Comment: Your regex will proceed all strings that start with http, https or www. But it doesn't care how do they end. So a link like "www.haha" would be also proceeded, although it isn't a proper link. But that doesn' solve your problem in the question. I just wanted to point out, as it can be a pitfall. The regex otherwise should work as it is for the mentioned example. Where does the problem comes, can not be guessed, because it maybe is caused by some other code, not presented in the question.

Comment: Okay I get it, thanks for explanations

Comment: It was definitely a quote issue. I have added quotes in the first parameter of receivedMessage.replace("...",...) and it worked.